# Derivative of linear combinations of powers $y^k$ to get $y^{(l)}y^m$.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

**Put simply:** Is it possible to build any product of a derivative of some order and some power of a function as a linear combination of differentiations of powers of said function?

**Simplest example i can think of where it is possible:**

$$y(t)y'(t) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial (y(t)^2)}{\partial t}$$

Using the notation: $$f^{(k)}(t) = \frac{\partial^k (f(t))}{\partial t^k}$$

Consider the equation

$$\frac{\partial ^{l}}{\partial t^l}\left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_ky(t)^k\right\} = y^{(e_1)}(t)y(t)^{e_2}$$

Is it possible to solve? That is: can we always find a bunch of constants $c_k$ to acquire equality?

**If not**, then would the more general ($l$ now variable with summation $k$):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left\{\frac{\partial^{l(k)}}{\partial t^{l(k)}} c_k y(t)^k\right\} = y^{(e_1)}(t)y(t)^{e_2}$$

be possible to solve?

There is something about the linearity of differentiation that makes me hope it would be possible. But I don't know how to show it.

Comment: It seems not: Counting derivatives and powers shows that the only derivative of a power in which a term of the form $y^{(l)} y^m$ can occur is $\partial_t^l(y^{m + l})$. But for $l > 1, m > 0$ this quantity contains other terms. For example, $y'' y$ appears only in $\partial_t^2 (y^3)$, but expanding this gives a term that is a multiple of $(y')^2 y$.

Comment: Hmm, yes I think you are right. I wonder which functions we would need to add or expand with to be able to do that. Maybe if we put the polynomials in exponentials?

Comment: It's not so clear that there's a good answer besides just permitting the quantities $y^{(l)} y^m$ themselves. If your goal is to write such quantities as $\partial_t^l f(y)$ for reasonable functions $f$, I expect this can't be done for $l > 1, m > 0$. Even glancing at the simplest case $l = 2, m = 1$ considered above this looks pretty hopeless.